# Iterative algorithm to find fixed points of Lipschitz continuous operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Let $T: \mathtt{D} \to \mathtt{D}$ be a Lipschitz continuous operator, where $\mathtt{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and compact. In particular,
$\|T(x) - T(y)\| \leqslant L \| x - y \|$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and positive constant $L>0$. Since $\mathtt{D}$ is convex and compact, Brouwer fixed point theorem guarantees existence of fixed point of $T$ i.e. there exists $x_0 \in \mathtt{D}$ such that $T(x_0) = x_0$.

When $L<1$, $T$ is contraction and banach fixed point theorem proves that Picard iterations converge. When $L \leqslant 1$, T is nonexpansive and Mann iterations provide convergence results (under some additional assumptions). But what about the case $L>1$ (Lipschitz constant is strictly greater than 1)?  Does there exists any iterative algorithm to approximate the fixed point of $T$? To be precise, does there exists an algorithm which produce sequence of iterates which converge to any fixed point of $T$?

Comment: Maybe Newton iteration is available?

Comment: I guess so. Maybe quasi newton methods will do because finding Jacobian or its inverse is surely impossible for me. Can you please tell me about possible convergence analysis or direct me to appropriate materials?